# Will I keep my local trophics if I create my first PSN account?

Tags: ps3

I've never had internet so I've never had my ps3 hooked up to the internet. I have gained about 10 plats playing solely offline, and worked really hard on that. I've just got a chance to bring my ps3 to my friends house and set up an account. Will my trophies sync with my account, or be deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they will sync, though maybe you have to start the game, I don't remember.

Comment: This is right, I made my PSN account about a year or two after the trophies had been implemented and they all synced when I made the account. Just make sure you make the PSN account on the same local Playstation profile, as only those of that account will be added.

Comment: Worked for me as well